Is there any way to Check that a GLB file is a valid or a corrupted file in c#?
I want to check that a GLB file is a valid GLB file or a corrupted File before doing any process on that GLB file.
I tried to load the file using the below code, but some valid GLB file I have which are given an exception. So trying to load the glb file is not a correct way to tell that the glb file is valid or a corrupted glb file.
The code :
try
{
    var model = SharpGLTF.Schema2.ModelRoot.Load("model.glb");
    // Successfully loaded the GLB file; it's valid.
    Console.WriteLine("GLB file is valid.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle validation errors.
    Console.WriteLine($"Error loading GLB: {ex.Message}");
}

I am getting the following exception for a Valid GLB File:

SharpGLTF.Validation.DataException: 'Accessor[13] TANGENT[181]:
Invalid TangentModel generated by <Microsoft GLTF Exporter 2.8.3.40>
seems to be malformed; Please, check the file at
https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/'

I checked the file in the glTF-Validator and according to it is is not valid, but it is loading when I am opening it using 3d Viewer.

What exception? Using library function to load file looks like a valid approach to me, it may not be the best, but should do the job.

I am getting this Below Exception
SharpGLTF.Validation.DataException: 'Accessor[13] TANGENT[181]: Invalid TangentModel generated by <Microsoft GLTF Exporter 2.8.3.40> seems to be malformed; Please, check the file at https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/'

Did you check if file is valid according to the khronos.org link you mentioned ? If it's not then it seems like Microsoft GLTF Exporter 2.8.3.40 that was used to geneate the file is not conformant and the file is indeed not valid.

According to the link, the file is invalid but it is loading when i am opening the glb file using 3d Viewer.

@ROHITNIKHARE I updated the question with the additional info from the comments, and also posted a complete answer.

The official validator is the final word on whether a file is valid, but 3D viewers are not necessarily going out of their way to fail on invalid files – failing validation is a strong sign that there could be issues in 3D viewers. An invalid tangent vector, in particular, is not an especially critical problem, and viewers may not spend the time required to validate each vertex's normals and tangents.

@DonMcCurdy even if an invalid tangent vector is not a critical problem, as you said yourself the official validator is the final word on the glb validity. Therefore it seems that the attempt to load the file as the OP did is still a good method to check the validity. Don't you agree ? (or maybe I misunderstood you)

Using glTF Validator is a good way to check validity of the file, yes. Authors of exporters, or services allowing users to upload glTF files, should in particular try to
validate models. Some of the things the validator reports are simply hints, like "this UV set may be unused," and are flagged with lower severity accordingly.
I don't know the OP's use case, but I don't think that every tool needs to run the entire validation suite before processing a glTF file, or to refuse to process models that fail validation. Depends on your goals, and the potential risks involved.

As you can see in the Wikipedia entry for glTF, it is:

An open standard developed and maintained by the Khronos Group.

(emphasis is mine)
Also from the link above:

glTF file uses one of two possible file extensions: .gltf (JSON/ASCII) or .glb (binary)

I.e. a .glb file is the binary version of the glTF file format, and the Khronos Group is in charge of this format.
If your file is rejected by the Khronos glTF validator, it means that it is not valid.
According to the exception message you posted it seems like the Microsoft GLTF Exporter 2.8.3.40 is non-conformant (and the 3D viewer probably support the non-conformant part(s)).
Nevertheless the file is not a valid glTF/glb file.
The bottom line:
Your method to try to load the file is a correct method for determining the validity of it.
You can use the glTF validator mentioned above to determine which part(s) in the file are invalid.
